# Indexing line segments with R-Tree

Tags: indexing, rtree

I have made a small unweighted graph consisting of 20 nodes and 28 edges. I would like to understand how a R-Tree indexing would index the the graph.

Could anyone explain how the R-tree indexed such line segments?

I have uploaded the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for mentioning. Actually I have a dataset of road networks and I am specifically trying to understand the Rtree indexing of that road network dataset. However, before running into code directly I would like to visually understand it. I reading the paper, however I have still not understood it. So, If someone has the experience of using the Rtree, then they would explain it on a simple term with visualization of small test case then that would be helpful. But now I see that this place is not for discussion. I don't think this is gonna be much help